# What does this syntax mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle
     boxOfficeGross:(NSNumber *)newBoxOfficeGross
            summary:(NSString *)newSummary;
```

What does this mean?  I've guessed that it returns id, and takes three params, but what does each part of the syntax mean?  I come from a Ruby/JS background and am finding this syntax a little hard to grasp.

Comment: Dave's answer below is solid, though I would add a link to the Objective-C developer's guide, as it is an excellent intro to the language.  Also, Objective-C **does not have named arguments** (not that you suggested it does... just don't make that easily made mistake as you learn the language)!

Comment: it's a function call in objective-c also called 'passing a message to an object'. You pass message to object like this: `[someobject processPersonWithFirstName:a secondName:b age:34];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an instance method (ie, not a static or "class" method) called `initWithTitle:boxOfficeGross:summary:` that returns an object of type `id` (generic object).  It takes three parameters: a String object, a Number object, and another String object.

You invoke it like this:

```
NSNumber * gross = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1878025999]
Movie * avatar = [[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Avatar"
                               boxOfficeGross:gross
                                      summary:@"Pocahontas in the 22nd century"];
//or you can do it all on one line, like so:
Movie * avatar = [[Movie alloc] initWithTitle:@"Avatar" boxOfficeGross:gross summary:@"Pocahontas in the 22nd century"];
```

Answer (score 4):

- `-` means that the method is an *instance method*, not a *class method*.
- `(id)` means it returns an `id`, as you surmised.
- `initWithTitle:`, `boxOfficeGross:`, and `summary:` are part of the method name. In Objective-C, each parameter generally has an associated method name part. The entire name of the method is `initWithTitle:boxOfficeGross:summary`.
- `(NSString *)`, etc., denote the type of the parameter.
- `newTitle`, etc., is the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `-` designates an instance method, whereas if it were a `+` it would be a class method.

The `(id)` is what the method will return, which is simply a reference to an object.

The rest of the line shows the parameters. When calling the function, you write out the part of each parameter before the `:`, such as `[class initWithTitle:@"my title"];`

The reason why there are two names for each parameter is because the method itself will refer to the variable by whatever is after the `:`, so the title will be `newTitle`.

This was confusing to me at first, but there are advantages to it.

Also, the parts of each parameter inside parenthesis are the object type of the parameter. `(NSString *)` is a pointer to a `NSString`. If you were to pass something that wasn't an `NSObject`, such as an `NSIntger`, you would not need the `*`. You'd simply do:
`-(id)initWithInteger:(NSIntger)newInteger;`